# keyboard combination to search forward in bash history

Tags: bash, history, keyboard-shortcuts

Pressing `ctrl-R` allows me to search thru command line history

Pressing `ctrl-R` allows me to go back in command history matches

What is the keyboard shortcut to jump forward in command history matches?

Sometimes you just pass the command you were looking for and want to go back

---

I found [this page](https://www.linux.org/threads/popular-keyboard-shortcuts-for-the-gnu-bash-shell.44645/) which says:

> Ctrl + r: Search the command history backward (use Ctrl + s to search forward)

but it doesn't seem to work (btw, I'm using terminator on ubuntu 22.04, also tried with gnome terminal)

Comment: a basic command like `cat ~/.bash_history | more` not working? Try als `grep <searchtext> ~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/47633)

TLDR;, add `stty -ixon` to you `.bashrc` file

---

You can search forward as well. From the bash info manual, "[8.2.5 Searching for Commands in the History](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html)":

> To search backward in the history for a particular string, type `C-r`.
> Typing `C-s` searches forward through the history.

The problem with Ctrl-S however is that sometimes collides with XON/XOFF flow control (in Konsole for instance). The searching is a readline feature however, and you should be able to bind it to some other key. Update: Simpler and better is just to disable XON/XOFF by running

```
stty -ixon
```